# Task Reminder to non-delegate

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook

I am developing a Task Reminder in Access to alert the concerning employees for the critical due tasks.

I have a table with the details about the due dates and I want to set the task to specific employees for the specific records.

I can set the task to my Outlook. Is there any way that I may set the task to other user's Outlook?

I want to accomplish this without setting up delegates or shared folders.

```
Dim outLookApp As Outlook.Application       
Dim outlookTask As Outlook.TaskItem     
Dim myDelegate As Outlook.Recipient    
Set outLookApp = CreateObject("outlook.application")         
Set outlookTask = outLookApp.createitem(olTaskItem)    
With outlookTaskoutlookTask.To = Me.Text33      
    .Subject = "Contract Expiry With In Month Of:" & Space(2) &Forms!frmrem!EmpName.Value       
    .body = "EmployeeName:" & Space(2) & Forms!frmrem!EmpName.Value  
    .reminderset = True  
    .duedate = Me.DOJ         
    .ReminderTime = Me.DOJ - 30 & " 8:00 AM"    
    .reminderplaysound = True        
    .Save        
End With    
MsgBox "Successfully task has been set ", vbInformation, "Set task Confirmd"        
End Sub
```

Comment: Review https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-another-person-s-mail-and-calendar-items-8B08BCD3-4FE7-45E7-9CCD-76E1877049C1

Comment: I want to accomplish this by using access database, not by setting up delegates or shared folders

Comment: Research indicates delegation must be set before VBA can manipulate other accounts.

Answer (score 0):

You may [assign a task](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Assign-a-task-d12c1869-1626-4873-bae1-e451f7fafdc2) which the receiver can accept.

The VBA code for this can be found here [TaskItem.Assign Method (Outlook)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/taskitem-assign-method-outlook).

```
Sub AssignTask() 

    Dim myItem As TaskItem 
    Dim myTaskAssignee As Recipient 

    Set MyItem = CreateItem(olTaskItem) 
    MyItem.Assign 

    Set myTaskAssignee = MyItem.Recipients.Add("Dan Wilson") 
    myTaskAssignee.Resolve 

    If myTaskAssignee.Resolved Then 
        myItem.Subject = "Prepare Agenda For Meeting" 
        myItem.DueDate = Now + 30 
        myItem.Display 
        myItem.Send 
    End If 

ExitRoutine:
    Set MyItem = Nothing
    Set myTaskAssignee = Nothing

End Sub
```